# Vagrant disable SSH Agent

Tags: ssh, vagrant, varying, vvv-wordpress

Getting the following when I am trying to run `Vagrant up`.

Have tried to re-provision etc. Even tried rolling back (in Time Machine) the `user/vagrant-local` directory & the `vagrant-local` directory where the sites all live.

> An error occurred in the underlying SSH library that Vagrant uses. The
>   error message is shown below. In many cases, errors from this library
>   are caused by ssh-agent issues. Try disabling your SSH agent or
>   removing some keys and try again.
>
> If the problem persists, please report a bug to the net-ssh project.
>
> timeout during server version negotiating

Comment: Also getting this error on Windows 10, Vagrant 1.8.5 with VirtualBox 5.1.2

Comment: If you need help with VVV go to the VVV github or our slack, I'm the project lead for VVV

Answer (score 9):

I was getting this exact error.

I upgraded from VirtualBox 5.0.x to 5.1.8 and the error went way.
After upgrading I did **vagrant destroy** and then **vagrant up** and the machine booted up without issues.

So this is what I have now:

- Windows 10 pro
- Vagrant 1.8.7
- VirtualBox 5.1.8

I also made sure everything else was updated. Don't forget to reboot.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Upgrading from 5.0.x to 5.1.30 fixed the same error for me on Mac.

Answer (score 8):

I have faced the same issue and done the following:

1. Send shutdown command to your VM (virtual machine)
2. Run the command again: vagrant up

ssh issue was resolved after this as VM has been restarted again.

Comment: I have solved the issue by two commands: "vagrant destroy --force" and "vagrant up --debug" ( In my case, the actual problem is with the "directory already existed." It has nothing to do with ssh or related stuff. :) Enjoy!!!

Comment: For my case following has worked. 
vagrant halt and vagrant up

Comment: I just powered off VM and Did `Vagrant up` and it resolved the error.

Comment: This worked instantly! Thanks @prashant

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue on this setup:

- Windows 11
- Vagrant 2.3.1
- VirtualBox 6.1.38

What seems to have solved the problem for me is this:

- run `vagrant destroy -f`
- temporarily disable "Use the WSL2 based engine" from Docker Desktop. Wait for Docker Desktop restart.
- run `vagrant up --debug`. The problem is still reported, but this time Vagrant recovers and runs to the end
- Verify `vagrant ssh` is working
- Re-enable "Use the WSL2 based engine". Wait for Docker Desktop restart.
- Verify things are still working (also after re-boot)